# Error while running asp.net application in hosting server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting following error

> a severe error occurred on the current command, the result any should be discarded

Error occurs regularly while uploading an excel file or xml file to database and processing it with generated .cs files in App_Code folder.

Please any can help me to resolve this issue.!

[image]

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=36409

Comment: i think `reindexing` the table may solve the problem